# Validation of request body AND request parameter in 1 step?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javax.validation

a question to validation of put calls to a REST endpoint using spring boot and javax.validation (not the spring validation).

You have the following method in the resource:

```
@PutMapping(...)
public Response getResult(@RequestBody @Valid myBody, @PathVariable @MyIdValidation long id) {

}
```

When I call the method, `myBody` gets validated and I get a  `MethodArgumentNotValidException` in my exception handler. But parameter `id` gets **not** validated!

Only if `myBody` is valid, `id` gets validated as well.

The only solution I found is to not use `@Valid`, and implement the validation of the body myself.

Are there better solutions?

TIA
Kibu

Comment: Any concrete example of `@MyIdValidation` ? and are you using JSR annotations on `myBody` too ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its doable by Spring MVC framework itself because framework handles `@RequestBody` and others like `@RequestParam` or `@PathVariable` differently by using different components. Also, both pieces need to be disconnected because you might not like to validate all arguments of a method.

`@RequestBody` is handled by `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` and validations are called from there & for params or path variable validations are done by `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor`.

So in my opinion, method arguments of a controller method are handled one by one by framework & are disconnected in logic so these validations can't be clubbed together.

Comment: I think you're right. Because when I use a custom validation annotion for the body instead of @Valid, everything is  validated in one step and I get a  ValidationConstraintException.

Comment: @kibuKuhn: if you are from Germany then I need a personal favor from you. Please share some way like email or skype etc thorough which I can reach you. Its regarding my relocation there. Please share if willing to provide some info kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

I've put some effort into this issue and started a project on [github](https://github.com/KibuKuhn/spring-validation)

It's possible to validate in one stop, but you need a different approach. Check out the project and test it.

Kibu